# Generate getters and setters for inner class. Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, setter, getter-setter, getter

How can I generate getters and setters for inner class in Eclipse? I found only such kind of info. which is not useful for answering my question: [that](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=7295) and [that](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=160344).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `Windows` set the cursor anywhere in the inner class and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Select the fields you want to generate the setters/getters for. Hit OK.

Apply the same process for the outer class.

Answer (score 1):

Set the cursor in the inner class or over the corresponding field  and choose the menu

> `Source > Generate Getters and Setters...`

or shortcut:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>`> Generate Getters and Setters...`

A dialog window should open where you can selected which Getters and/or Setters should be generated.

By default, it is also possible to just type the corresponding method name (e.g. `getName`) and use autocomplete <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to create the method.